# substr in IE7 not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying the following code to extract first few characters from a string stored in a variable.

```
title.substr(0,35)+"_"+var1+"_"+var2+var3;
```

At the above line IE7 throws an error:
Object doesn't support this property or method.

Tried: substring and slice as well. Still same issue.

Comment: I don't really think this is a browser or browser version issue.

Comment: title holds a string value.

Comment: To be sure, there are some things to check: First, what is 'typeof(title)'? Second, is there an error with 'title.substr(0,35)' omitting the var1/2/3 parts?

Answer (score 1):

It is quite apparent from the error message that title is not of type string.

Try this:

```
var title = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
console.log(title.substr(0,15));
```

I suspect your title variable is not of type String. To debug it, try 
`console.log(typeof(title))` in your own code.

Check the console and see what you get.